# Stuck Installing Selenium Server for Python

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to use the Selenium standalone server with Python. However, when I type

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\Java.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar
```

into the command prompt, the setup gets stuck displaying

```
May 22, 2013 3:38:18 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
15:38:18.388 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.21-b01
15:38:18.389 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
15:38:18.394 INFO - v2.32.0, with Core v2.32.0. Built from revision 6c40c18
15:38:18.473 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4444/wd/hub
15:38:18.474 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
15:38:18.475 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server
/driver]
15:38:18.475 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
15:38:18.476 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
15:38:18.498 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@166faa
c
15:38:18.499 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
15:38:18.501 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
15:38:18.502 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@144752d
```

I'm not sure how to get around this problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a problem - that looks to me like the selenium server has started successfully, and is now running. Do you have a problem connecting to it and running a script?

Comment: Ok, I thought once the server had started running, I would then be able to enter commands into the command prompt but it doesn't appear that way.

I have managed to get it working using Python, thanks.